# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, no analog sound from Realtek ALC889

Tags: 18.04, sound, realtek

I get sound from the Realtex ALC889 on my motherboard in Windows 10, and I used to get it with Ubuntu 17.10. But when I upgraded to 18.04 Ubuntu no longer recognizes the device. Under the Sound Settings I get:
HDMI/DisplayPort2 - GT216 HDMI Audio Controller
Digital Output (S/PDIF) - Built-in Audio

The HDMI drives the sound on my 24" TV, but the TV has lousy sound. I want a stereo analog output to drive my separate speakers.

I get:

```
~$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed in a recent update.

Comment: **@MrShunz & reviewers:** This is a message from OP saying it’s solved. Please don’t delete this answer, although not very specific, vote to close the question.

Comment: I'm still having this issue with fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Realtek ALC889. Front panel audio doesn't work, no analog audio, no sound; none of the alsamixer or pavucontrol solutions work